# SQL How to select column according to column value

Tags: mysql, join

I'd like to be able to select a column according to the value in an other column. With a simple example:
From

```
Name  Status       Activities
A     Full         Tennis
B     Discounted   Badminton
C     Full         Badminton
```

And

```
Sport      Full   Discounted
Tennis      70    60
Badminton   110   90
```

I would like to output :

```
 Name  Due         
 A     70     
 B     90
 C     110
```

To join the first two tables only highlight the need to select one column from the value in an other one. 
My choices to store the data may be bad . Any idea ?

Comment: you tagged this question as PHP but there is not PHP code. Can you share us what you are trying to do in PHP. It will help us identify what you are doing wrong.

Comment: Please read & act on hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & [mcve]--show what you have tried & considered & what parts you can do. Also this is a faq.

Answer (score 1):

Your data storage choice is fine although it might be better to have `id` values in each table and link the people table to the dues table on the dues `id` value rather than a name. Given your structure as it is, you can get the results you want with a simple `JOIN`:

```
SELECT p.Name
     , CASE WHEN p.Status = 'Full' THEN d.Full ELSE d.Discounted END AS Due
FROM people p
JOIN dues d ON d.Sport = p.Activities
```

Output:

```
Name    Due
A       70
B       90
C       110
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b5b144/1)

Comment: I was looking for a solution where adding a different price would be easier ( especially if there are a lot of prices), but that will do the trick !

Comment: @SimonLang you would need to further normalise your data to achieve that, having a table with `Sport`, `Status` and `Price` columns; then you could `JOIN` on `Sport` and `Status` to get the price. If you are going to expand to a lot of prices, this would be a much better way to go.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is your data isn't normalized making this a more difficult query.  One method would be to normalize the data.  One way to do this is in a derived table; another would be to structure the table so it is normalized.

Since the combination of status and a sport yields a rate then the data isn't normalized as you have two rates columns.

```
SELECT Name, Due
FROM A
INNER JOIN (SELECT Sport, 'Full' as Status, Full as Due FROM B UNION ALL
            SELECT Sport, 'Discounted' as Status, Discounted as Due FROM B) B
 on A.Activities = B.Sport
and A.Status = B.Status
```

Instead of a table like this:

```
Sport      Full   Discounted
Tennis      70    60
Badminton   110   90
```

This is normalized as you can add sports/rate types and new rates w/o changing structure.  If you needed to add a new rate type in the prior format, you'd be adding a table.

```
Sport      RateType      Rate
Tennis     Full          70
Tennis     Discounted    60
Badminton  Full          110
Badminton  Discounted    90
```

This way you can add sports and different rates w/o changing code.

```
Tennis     Weekend    20
Complete   Family     575
```

Technically you should have a RateType Table Which would list the rate Name and and ID so that you can have a complete list of all available rateTypes that can then be tied to each sport and $rate as needed.  You could also show when rate types have been depreciated so they can't be selected new but allow existing ones to persist.

Comment: What would you mean by structuring the table ?

Comment: Make full and discounted types in the table along with a column for rates. Status or rate type same concept

Comment: As it stands the table doesn't seem normalized or scalable if a premium or holiday or guest or... Rates needed to be added later

Comment: Of course ! Thank you very much for making that clear :)